# How to remove lines from file based on random list of lines file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a large txt file (long_list) and another txt file listing rows that I would like to delete from it (short_list).

```
#long list
seq 10000 > long_list

#rows to delete
for i in `seq 30`; do echo $(($RANDOM % 10000)); done > short_list
```

I have found a way to do this for a few specific rows:

```
sed -e '648d;649d' long_list
```

But I have a list of rows to remove that is hundreds of lines long, and I want to input from a file. Can anybody help?

Comment: yes, sorry for the duplication. once i removed the -i option and saved output into new txt file, i now have exactly what i wanted. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!(FNR in a)' short_list long_list
```

Lines are printed if the number of record of the current file `FNR` that is not part of the array `a` filled with the content of `short_list`